# Is the group of all determinants of all invertible $n \times n$-matrices isomorphic to $\langle\mathbb{R}^*, \cdot\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am doing Linear Algebra and Abstract Algebra simultaneously, and in Linear Algebra class, going through determinants, I thought of something interesting (for a freshman just learning the subjects, that is):

Is the group of all determinants of all invertible matrices isomorphic to the non-zero real numbers under multiplication? While I expect the answer to be yes, there may be some details that I have missed/misunderstood.

Comment: I change ${<}\mathbb R^*,\cdot{>}$ to $\langle\mathbb R^*,\cdot\rangle$.  That is standard usage.

Comment: Thank you, still slightly new to TeX.

Comment: In fact it's not *isomorphic* but **equal** to $(\Bbb R^*,\cdot)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Consider the diagonal matrix with $r, 1, 1, ..., 1$ on the diagonal, where $r$ is a nonzero real. That has determinant $r$ so "det" is a surjective map from $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ to $ \mathbb R^{*}$. And since $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$, it's actually a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Since determinants of invertible matrices with real entries are just nonzero real numbers, the question is whether every nonzero real number is the determinant of some such matrix.  If $a$ is a real number, then it is the determinant of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}$.

So the answer is affirmative.